# JavaFX: Location is required

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

Esse é o código main, estou com problemas em relação a FXMLLoader, pois já tentei diversas formas e o caminho nunca é encontrado.

```
package com.quixada.ufc.fbd.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.quixada.ufc.fbd.viewFXController.OnChangeScreen;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class MainJavaFX extends Application {

private static Stage stage;
private static Scene mainScene;
private static Scene detailsScene;
private static ArrayList<OnChangeScreen> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        stage = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setTitle("Exemplo");
        AnchorPane fxmlMain = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../com/quixada/ufc/fbd/view/ViewLogin.fxml"));
        mainScene = new Scene(fxmlMain,400,400);

        AnchorPane fxmlDetails = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/src/com.quixada.ufc.fbd.view/ViewCadastro.fxml"));
        detailsScene = new Scene(fxmlDetails,400,400);

        primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void changeScreen(String scr, Object userData) {
    switch (scr) {
    case "main":
        stage.setScene(mainScene);
        notifyAllListeners("main", userData);
        break;
    case "details":
        stage.setScene(detailsScene);
        notifyAllListeners("details", userData);

    }
}

public static void changeScreen(String scr) {
    changeScreen(scr, null);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public static void addOnChangeScreenListener(OnChangeScreen newListener) {
    listeners.add(newListener);
}

private static void notifyAllListeners(String newScreen, Object userData) {
    for (OnChangeScreen l : listeners)
        l.onScreenChanged(newScreen, userData);
}
```

Estou organizando meus pacotes da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me dar alguma ajuda?

Comment: Olá, Samuel. Poste o código ao invés de imagens dele.

Comment: É realmente um problema no caminho pros seus FXML, no caso se o fxml estiver no mesmo pacote você pode por simplesmente o nome do arquivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É apenas uma confusão na utilização do método getResource, veja os exemplos:

Recurso no mesmo pacote:

```
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("arquivo.fxml"));
```

Recurso em pacote diferente:

```
// Considerando br.com.empresa.origem e br.com.empresa.diretorio 
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/br/com/empresa/diretorio/arquivo.fxml"));
```

Não precisa por `src` nem `../` a não ser que seja fora da pasta src.

Answer (score 1):

Ambos estão corretos amigos, porém acabou que era apenas um problema de biblioteca faltando. Eu estava usando a biblioteca jfoenix e ao trocar de máquina acabei esquecendo de exportar o novo caminho do jfoenix.jar, por conta disso o programa não executava.

O código ficou assim para quem tiver curiosidade:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        stage = primaryStage;

        primaryStage.setTitle("MyApp");
        AnchorPane fxmlLogin = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/quixada/ufc/fbd/view/ViewLogin.fxml"));
        LoginScene = new Scene(fxmlLogin,1077,720);

        AnchorPane fxmlCadastro = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/quixada/ufc/fbd/view/ViewCadastro.fxml"));
        CadastroScene = new Scene(fxmlCadastro,1077,720);

        AnchorPane fxmlMain = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/quixada/ufc/fbd/view/ViewMainUsuario.fxml"));
        MainScene = new Scene(fxmlMain, 1077, 720);

        AnchorPane fxmlDetalhes = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/quixada/ufc/fbd/view/DetalhesPontoTurisiticoView.fxml"));
        DetalhesScene = new Scene(fxmlDetalhes, 1077, 720);


        primaryStage.setScene(LoginScene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AnchorPane fxmlMain = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/ViewLogin.fxml"));
```